# transition matrix equal to zero using hmmlearn

Tags: hmmlearn

I am using HMMlearn. I have 4 sets of different observations, that I have concatenated them. I used fit, to learn hmm.

first, why transition matrix is equal to zero?

Second, why the modell.means_  results in a matrix with the same dimension of the data?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. the problem was that the data was like a 1-d array with length 1. I fixed it with using np.reshape(data, (-1, 1))